# Show that $2\cos z = e^{iz} + e^{-iz}$. Do I need absolute convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, absolute-convergence

I'm reading Conway's "Functions of one complex variable". Define

$$e^z =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$$
$$\cos z =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

It is already shown that these converge for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

I'm asked to show that

$$e^{iz} + e^{-iz} = 2 \cos z$$

I have two questions:

(1) Is my attempt correct?
(2) Did I need absolute convergence anywhere? (The author claims that this should be necessary)

$$e^{iz} + z^{-iz} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(iz)^n}{n!} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-iz)^n}{n!} \quad (definition)$$
$$= \sum_{k=0}^3 \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(iz)^{4n+k}}{(4n+k)!} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-iz)^{4n+k}}{(4n+k)!}\right) \quad (**, see \ lemma  \ down \ with \ k =4)$$

$$= 2 \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{4n}}{(4n)!}- \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{4n+2}}{(4n+2)!} \right) \quad (simplifying \ sums)$$

$$= 2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z^{4n}}{(4n)!}- \frac{z^{4n+2}}{(4n+2)!} \right) \quad (linearity)$$
$$= 2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n z^{2n}}{(2n)!} = 2\cos z \quad (** \ with \ k =2, definition)$$

Note that I used the following lemma (**):

$$k \geq 2, \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \mathrm{\ converges}\implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_{kn} + \dots a_{kn+(k-1)})$$

This can be proven by observing that the right series has partial sums that are a subsequence of the partial sums of the left series.

Comment: I think you need absolute convergence to be able to permute the terms of the infinite sum.  So any operation you did that effectively "adds the terms in a different order" is valid because the series were absolutely convergent to begin with

Comment: Can you be more specific which lines I did this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is too complex (although it seems correct). Note that$$e^{iz}=1+iz-\frac{z^2}2-i\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+i\frac{z^5}{5!}+\cdots$$and that$$e^{-iz}=1-iz-\frac{z^2}2+i\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-i\frac{z^5}{5!}+\cdots$$and therefore\begin{align}e^{iz}+e^{-iz}&=2-2\frac{z^2}2+2\frac{z^4}{4!}-\cdots\\&=2\cos z.\end{align}And absolute convergence is not needed. All I used about series was that if$$a=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\text{ and }b=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n,$$then$$a+b=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_n+b_n).$$This does not require absolute convergence.

Comment: But, is the termwise addition even possible without assuming some type of (maybe absolute) convergence? I mean, we run into serious problems when doing so with, let's say the harmonic series.

Comment: In my sentence the begins with “All I used about series”, I assume that both series converge. That's quite enough. I don't understand your reference to the harmonic series.

Comment: Ah, okay. This assumption is what I was missing. Regarding my reference to the harmonic series: we may add (and subtract) the harmonic series and its alternating counterpart resulting in a divergent series even though one of its summands was convergent. To put it into a nutshell: I was confused about manipulating infinite series *without any restrictions* on their convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you wouldn't use Euler's formula to do this:  $e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z$?

Then the result follows easily.

Answer (score 0):

In the first permutation you need absolute convergence. For a counterexample think of $$\log 2=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dotsc=\left(1+\frac13+\dotsc\right)-\left(\frac12+\frac14+\dotsc\right)=\infty-\infty=\text{undefined}$$

Comment: What equality do you mean in my answer?

Comment: The second equality where you split and rearrange the two original sums into four other sums.

Comment: I don't think I need it there. I just applied linearity and the lemma I wrote down in my post. Maybe I'm overseeing something though.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos answer doesn't need absolute convergence, yours I'm not sure because you're not applying correctly your lemma (which is correct). In the lemma you group only but you preserve the order (and hence the partial sums are a subsequence), whereas in your proof you're shuffling the terms.